# codeigniter convert tinyint type record to boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any tricks to convert returned tinyint record type to boolean in codeigniter?

I have this record:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "Go to store",
    "completed": "1"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "Learn Angular",
    "completed": "0"
}]
```

I want to convert the *completed* attribute to boolean, so the result will be like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "body": "Go to store",
    "completed": true
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "body": "Learn Angular",
    "completed": false
}]
```

how to do that? thanks before

Answer (score 0):

you should convert it outside the json, just try:

```
$completed = ($completed === 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($yourjsondata as $j)
    $j['completed'] = ($j['completed'] === "1");
```